# help me to Solve a trick equation

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve a trick question that my teacher gave to me.

This question is related to linear algebra.

I have no idea on where to start with this question. I need some guidance in getting started.
$$
x-\sin(x) = \pi/4
$$

Comment: Soooooooooooo what is the question?

Comment: How is this linear algebra?

Answer (score 2):

You will not get an explicit solution.  There is exactly one real root, around $1.76634$, which can be found by numerical root finding.  I am sure that is what [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x-sin%28x%29=pi/4) uses.  The techniques are described in any numerical analysis text, but not linear algebra.